# add empty column to existing DataFrame and populate it with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

The real dataframe is very big, here I put a very simplified example.

Suppose *df* is my existing dataframe:

```
dti = pd.date_range("2021-06-17", periods=4, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": dti, "col2": [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]})
df = df.set_index("col1")
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["new_col1", "new_col2"])
```

*new_df* is the new dataframe that I will fill row by row with a **for loop**:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    n = row["col2"]-0.5
    new_df = new_df.append({'new_col1': index, 'new_col2': n}, ignore_index=True)
        
new_df["new_col1"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df.new_col1)
new_df = new_df.set_index("new_col1")
```

once the new dataframe has been created, I assign a new column to *df*:

```
df = df.assign(new_col = new_df.values)
```

I would like to avoid the creation of a new dataframe, are there any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `df['col2'] -= df['col2'] - 0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this solution:

```
df["new_col"] = np.nan
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    n = row["col2"]-0.5 # example 
    df.at[index,"new_col"] = n
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the logic of your question correctly ...
you can modify your current df without creating a copy or a new one by using the inplace parameter. See below for an example of a solution to your problem.

```
dti = pd.date_range("2021-06-17", periods=4, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": dti, "col2": [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]})

df = df.set_index("col1")           # assuming this line generates your initial df
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['col1'], inplace=True)
df['col3'] = df['col2'] - 0.5
df.rename(columns={'col2': 'col1', 'col3': 'col2'}, inplace=True)
```